# animate.css is animating when the page is loading

Tags: css, animation, animate.css

I am using animate.css for my Web site and i used a bootstrap carousel slider it is searched on google and placed in my website. Its working fine But after that my animate.css  is not working properly means all animated elements in the HTML page are animating when page loading.
ex: i am using fadeInRight animated class below the page but it is not working when i am going to page down and when i refresh the page  at that particular element its working fine. please solve this

[please check the site](http://project1.uidevelopers.tk)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *Reveal Animations When You Scroll*, this is what you're looking for:

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

CSS animations cannot be delayed based on the scroll position. So, first, you'll need to download and include the *wow.min.js* file to your page like this:

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

And then add the animation to your html element by adding the class '`wow`' followed by the animation name in animate.css:

```
 <section class="wow slideInLeft">
 </section>
```

For more advanced options related to timing the delay etc, refer: http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use wow.js for animating elements when it's on viewport area.
**HTML:**

```
<section class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">
            </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
```

**js:**

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          new WOW().init();
          </script>
```

check the jquery plugin [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html)